# MySQL date range: ocurrences among same dates

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL table which has a payment_date row.
I'm getting the rows from date X and date Y.
I would like to print the number of occurrences per date.

For example:

```
payment_date
2011-07-25
2011-07-24
2011-07-25
2011-06-13
```

I would need to return that in:

```
2011-07-25 got 2 payments
2011-07-24 got 1 payments
2011-06-13 got 1 payment
```

With this info I'm doing a plot, with X axis: date, and Y axis: number of payments.

My query by now is:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_pay
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(payment_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
BETWEEN '$payment_date_from'
AND
DATE '$payment_date_to'
GROUP BY DATE(payment_date)
```

[don't know!!!!]

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
payment_date,count(*) as tot
FROM table_pay
WHERE payment_date
BETWEEN '$payment_date_from'
AND
'$payment_date_to'
GROUP BY payment_date
order by tot desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this, can't test it right now so please respond whether it works as you are expect

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(payment_date, '%Y-%m-%d'), COUNT(*)
FROM table_pay
WHERE payment_date BETWEEN '$payment_date_from' AND '$payment_date_to'
GROUP BY payment_date
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a query like the following (assuming payment_date is a date) :

```
Select payment_date, count(*) as paymentcount from table_pay where payment_date between 'startdate' and 'enddate' group by payment_date
```